# Window.getSelection undefined in Firefox - case sensitive

Tags: javascript, firefox

I don't know if this is specific to Firefox or not but it seems that 'Window' is case sensitive in Firefox javascript.

```js
alert(Window.getSelection);
```

This returns `undefined` even if you have something selected.

However this works:

```js
alert(window.getSelection);
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icc97/6zj2fqqz/) for the difference.

But as you'll see above - the SO syntax highlighting highlights the upper case 'Window' and also the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection) suggests again that you should use the capitalised version too.

I first spotted this issue when trying to use it in bookmarks - which have the same problem. If you create a bookmark with `javascript:alert(Window.getSelection)` it will return undefined if you highlight a word and then click the bookmark.

**Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrect?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uppercase `Window` is the type, and this type has methods such as `Window.getWindow()`.

The lowercase `window` is the instance. Basically the browser is doing this:

```
var window = Window.getWindow();
```

Then from the `window` object you can do `getSelection`.

In some browsers you can access the object through prototype:

```
Window.prototype.getSelection
```

If you look deeper into the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) you can see that they actually use the lowercase version. I would say the reason why it is uppercase in the title and on the page you visited is because they are trying to show that its a method from the Window object.

*Note: every browser is different so your browser may assign the window object differently, I use safari.*

Comment: Yeah - should have looked that step further - as you say they use the lower case in the Window getSelection code